# what's does Build Sync means in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, build, sbt

I have an sbt project, and out of nowhere it started a build sync engaging 2 processes running. It's taking 50 mns so far.

what's actually happening? can I stop it?

Comment: You may have enabled automatic project refresh on change. You can disable it in the sbt preferences. Sometimes if multiple sbt processes are running they block each other resolving dependencies.

Comment: @JustinKaeser  thanks do you know the specific setting to disable?

Comment: Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | sbt | disable "use auto-import"

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ performs a 'build sync' whenever it needs to integrate with external build tools.

It updates it's internal project structure model in order to match that which is defined in SBT.

Can you stop it? Sure, it might be locked up and unable to continue, but it will have the side effects of the IntelliJ project model potentially not matching the SBT one.

The good news is that it will do this periodically anyway, or you can force it to sync again with SBT. So there is very little chance of harm in stopping it.

If this is the first SBT project you have set up, it may be downloading slow/unavailable dependencies, or it may have unintentionally blocked itself, IntelliJ and SBT don't always integrate the best, so some patience and jiggling is occasionally needed.

**Edit:**

Click, `File>Project Structure` and have a look at Project/Modules/Libraries.

This is a UI that shows IntelliJ's Project Structure Model.

As for SBT's, I'm not sure where and how well this is documented, but it's essentially what you define in build.sbt

Comment: `It updates it's internal project structure model in order to match that which is defined in SBT.`  what do you mean by that ? do you have any resource where i can read about it i searched by could not find any. thanks

Comment: I have a project without a single file with *.sbt extension, and yet the Build->Sync is performed...